# Create Excel Funtion to return the name of the sheet

Tags: excel, vba, function

I am attempting to create a function to return the name of the sheet where the function is located. However the below code returns the active sheet not the static sheet where the function is located.
I previously had a standard excel formula to give me the sheet name, which I can go back to if there isn't a way for vba to return the sheet where the function is located?

Sheet Name "TTD"

Excel Formula
+FileSheetName(C1)

=TTD

VBA Function

```
Function FileSheetName(aCellLocation)

    Application.Volatile

    aCellLocation = aCellLocation.Address
    Set aCellLocation = Range(aCellLocation)
    aSheetName = aCellLocation.Parent.Name

    FileSheetName = aSheetName

End Function
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use application.caller:
No need to use a range because the range.parent.name will give the sheetname of the range, not where the Function is located, (which could be different)

```
Function FileSheetName2()
    FileSheetName2 = Application.Caller.Parent.Name
End Function
```

Comment: Excellent, exactly what I was looking for! I love it when the answer is so simple.

Answer (score 0):

Your function argument is already a range - no need to get the address and then create a range from that:

```
Function FileSheetName(aCellLocation As Range)
    Application.Volatile 
    FileSheetName = aCellLocation.Parent.Name
End Function
```

Here:

```
Set aCellLocation = Range(aCellLocation)
```

the scope of `Range` defaults to the active sheet: that's why your result is wrong when the sheet with the formula is not the selected sheet.